# Google Maps Overlapping Marker doesn't return the correct clicked Marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing an Android application where there are a lot of markers in the map. Several markers are overlapping since I customize the marker so that it has rectangle view.

The problem occurs when the marker that has overlapping section is clicked on the overlapping section area. The OnMarkerClick gives me the supposed-to-be-clicked Marker. But it returns the Marker that has the lowest z-index on the overlapping area.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBeSQ.png)

For example, let's say the markers are all the rectangle (green, red, and blue). I tried to clicked where the red, blue, and green rectangle are overlapped (which is the bottom right of the red rectangle). But the API returned the green marker.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: share your code this shouldn't be happening because in case of overlapping marker the marker with higher z-index in drawn on top of marker that has lower z-index

Comment: it is, but I use custom marker, so it appears bigger, and the overlapping section is not as big as the marker (let's say only half of it), and when I clicked the overlapping part, the clicked marker is the one that has lower z-index

Comment: can you share a image so that we can have a clear picture and I'll be able to help you better

Comment: I've implemented the same thing but i haven't received issue in overlapping marker if i double click on the marker position marker gets selected as i required

Comment: same for me too can you share your code. It might be the case you have implemented something wrong

Comment: unfortunately the code is quite complex, but all I did about marker is only adding it to maps, and when set on marker click listener on map

Comment: hey there, I created a simple project that replicate my problem, please do try to clone https://github.com/syntaxerror007/maps-sample, thanks